# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python-2.7, typeerror

I'm executing the following snippet on python 2.7:

```
i=0
j=3
a=['A','B','B','A']
while(a[i]=="A" & i<j):
    #do something
```

And I am getting this error.

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831905/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-str)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: It might look similar but the operators are different, if you see. I wasn't aware that the solution would be similar for different operators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&` is "bitwise and" operand in Python , you should use `and` instead

from wiki.python.org:

> x & y :  Does a "bitwise and". Each bit of the output is 1 if the
>   corresponding bit of x AND of y is 1, otherwise it's 0.

"bitwise and" works like this:

```
>>> 1 & 0
0
>>> 0 & 0
0
>>> 1 & 1
1
```

Comment: The possible answer of :"similar question" doesnt solve my problem.  How do you suggest I solve this error?

Answer (score -1):

You need to put brackets around the two conditions like below.

```
i=0
j=3
a=['A','B','B','A']
while((a[i]=="A") & (i<j)):
    #do something
```

refer below link for more detailed explanation
[Difference between 'and' (boolean) vs. '&' (bitwise) in python. Why difference in behavior with lists vs numpy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646463/difference-between-and-boolean-vs-bitwise-in-python-why-difference-i)

Comment: Do you really think that they wanted to use a bitwise operation in this case?